# Project Euler 10 - Why the first python code runs much faster than the second one?

Tags: python, primes, number-theory

The 10th problem in Project Euler:

> The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
>
> Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

I found this snippet :

```
sieve = [True] * 2000000 # Sieve is faster for 2M primes
def mark(sieve, x):
    for i in xrange(x+x, len(sieve), x):
        sieve[i] = False

for x in xrange(2, int(len(sieve) ** 0.5) + 1):
    if sieve[x]: mark(sieve, x)

print sum(i for i in xrange(2, len(sieve)) if sieve[i])
```

published [here](http://www.s-anand.net/euler.html)
which run for 3 seconds.

I wrote this code:

```
def isprime(n):
    for x in xrange(3, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True

sum=0;
for i in xrange(1,int(2e6),2):
    if isprime(i):
        sum += i
```

I don't understand why my code (the second one) is much slower?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your algorithm is checking every number individually from 2 to N (where N=2000000) for primality.

Snippet-1 uses the **[sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)** algorithm, discovered about 2200 years ago. 
It does not check every number but:

- Makes a "sieve" of all numbers from 2 to 2000000.
- Finds the first number (2), marks it as prime, then deletes all its multiples from the sieve.
- Then finds the next undeleted number (3), marks it as prime and deletes all its multiples from the sieve.
- Then finds the next undeleted number (5), marks it as prime and deletes all its multiples from the sieve.
- ...
- Until it finds the prime 1409 and deletes all its multiples from the sieve.
- Then all primes up to 1414 ~= sqrt(2000000) have been found and it stops
- The numbers from 1415 up to 2000000 do not have to be checked. All of them who have not been deleted are primes, too.

So the algorithm produces all primes up to N.

Notice that it does not do any division, only additions (not even multiplications, and not that it matters with so small numbers but it might with bigger ones). Time complexity is `O(n loglogn)` while your algorithm has something near `O(n^(3/2))` (or `O(n^(3/2) / logn)` as @Daniel Fischer commented), assuming divisions cost the same as multiplications.

From the Wikipedia (linked above) article:

> Time complexity in the random access machine model is O(n log log n) operations, a direct consequence of the fact that the [prime harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_harmonic_series) asymptotically approaches `log log n`.

(with `n = 2e6` in this case)

Comment: why it is O(n log logn), is n= log(2e6) or n =2e6?

Comment: The trial division stops at the square root, so its complexity is better than O(n^2), off the top of my head, I'd say O(n^1.5 / log n), but I haven't counted the composites with large smallest prime factors, so it may be slightly worse (upper bound O(n^1.5)).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh, you are most probably right, I'll correct it.

Comment: The counting results (done by F.J) seem to favour these, too. Both `O(nloglogn)` and `O(n^1.5)`.

Comment: The sieve doesn't use any multiplication. It just uses additions. (as you can see in the code above)

Answer (score 4):

The first version pre-computes all the primes in the range and stores them in the `sieve` array, then finding the solution is a simple matter of adding the primes in the array. It can be seen as a form of [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

The second version tests for each number in the range to see if it is prime, repeating a lot of work already made by previous calculations.

In conclusion, the first version avoids re-computing values, whereas the second version performs the same operations again and again.

Comment: The performance is not due to pre-computing the primes. It's due to the way they are precomputed.

Comment: Calling the Sieve of Eratosthenes a memoized trial division algorithm does not do it proper credit.

Answer (score 2):

To easily understand the difference, try thinking how many times each number will be used as a potential divider:

In your solution, the number 2 will be tested for EACH number when that number will be tested for being a prime. Every number you pass along the way will then be used as a potential divider for every next number.

In the first solution, once you stepped over a number you never look back - you always move forward from the place you reached. By the way, a possible and common optimization is to go for odd numbers only after you marked 2:

```
mark(sieve, 2)
for x in xrange(3, int(len(sieve) ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
    if sieve[x]: mark(sieve, x)
```

This way you only look at each number once and clear out all of its multiplications forward, rather than going through all possible dividers again and again checking each number with all its predecessors, and the `if` statement prevents you from doing repeated work for a number you previously encountered.

Answer (score 2):

As Óscar's answer indicates, your algorithm repeats a lot of work.  To see just how much processing the other algorithm saves, consider the following modified version of the `mark()` and `isprime()` functions, which keep track of how many times the function has been called and the total number of for loop iterations:

```
calls, count = 0, 0
def mark(sieve, x):
    global calls, count
    calls += 1
    for i in xrange(x+x, len(sieve), x):
        count += 1
        sieve[i] = False
```

After running the first code with this new function we can see that `mark()` is called 223 times with a total of 4,489,006 (~4.5 million) iterations in the for loop.

```
calls, count = 0
def isprime(n):
    global calls, count
    calls += 1
    for x in xrange(3, int(n**0.5)+1):
        count += 1
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

If we make a similar change to your code, we can see that `isprime()` is called 1,000,000 (1 million) times with 177,492,735 (~177.5 million) iterations of the for loop.

Counting function calls and loop iterations isn't always a conclusive way to determine why an algorithm is faster, but generally less steps == less time, and clearly your code could use some optimization to reduce the number of steps.